# Parsing XML string in Perl

Tags: perl

I am appending an xml string with the following attributes:

```
$xml_mess = $xml_mess . "<origRef>S5J982RH</origRef>\n<newRef>S5J982RH</newRef>"
```

There is no guarantee that both `origRef` and `newRef` will be present in all cases.

With this in mind, I  would like to parse `$xml_mess` in the next line and perform the following operations.

- When `origRef` has a value, I want the data field for `newRef` to be blanked out (if it exists).
- When `newRef` has a value, I want the data field for `oldRef` to be replaced with `newRef`.

What is the best way of achieving this in Perl?

Comment: If you are building the XML from scratch, use a template system or at least build it step by step rather than manipulating something you've already built.

Comment: "_What is the best way of achieving this_"  --- use an XML parser to append the string, and once you are at it implement your logic as well.  If this is how your document is built to start with, then use a parser to do what you need to the string to be added first, then add it.

Comment: Your code seems guaranteed to produce XML that is not well-formed. You need to insert your new nodes **before** the original closing tag, not after it. Which why you should use an XML-aware tool for manipulating XML.

Comment: There is a requirement from the downstream system to receive down unconventional XML. We are merely adhering to its requirements.

Comment: There is no such thing as "unconventional XML". Your document is either well-formed XML or not XML :-)

Comment: If you haven't already found a solution then I guess it will be easier to answer your question if you can provide so examples and what you are trying to build.